# Using Bootstrap to paginate a set number of <p> elements on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

The application I work with serves 'article pages' consisting of many paragraphs using `<p>` element, now I want to paginate these paragraphs, suppose 15 paragraphs in three pages, with 5 paragraphs in each page.

What the Bootstrap [tutorial](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#pagination) explains is based on list elements, I am sure there must have been a way to implement this for other elements?

I came across another good plugin called [Pajinate](http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/), but it requires list elements explicitly!

Does Bootstrap or any plug in out there offers a solution where we can apply pagination based on any specific HTML element or CSS class?  My problem is to find one that I can apply to `<p>` element.

Comment: Bootstrap is only used for visual elements. 
Pajinate will actually cut the pages. Best way I believe is do it severside

Comment: Exactly. I must say now my problem is properly defined. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using a jquery plugin or server-side paging you can make a fairly simple paging implementation for Bootstrap using jQuery and the Bootstrap pagination class..

```
var listElement = $('#pageStuff');
var perPage = 2; 
var numItems = listElement.children().size();
var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

$('.pager').data("curr",0);

var curr = 0;
while(numPages > curr){
  $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo('.pager');
  curr++;
}

$('.pager .page_link:first').addClass('active');

listElement.children().css('display', 'none');
listElement.children().slice(0, perPage).css('display', 'block');

$('.pager li a').click(function(){
  var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf() - 1;
  goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
});

function previous(){
  var goToPage = parseInt($('.pager').data("curr")) - 1;
  if($('.active').prev('.page_link').length==true){
    goTo(goToPage);
  }
}

function next(){
  goToPage = parseInt($('.pager').data("curr")) + 1;
  if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
    goTo(goToPage);
  }
}

function goTo(page){
  var startAt = page * perPage,
    endOn = startAt + perPage;

  listElement.children().css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).css('display','block');
  $('.pager').attr("curr",page);
}
```

Place all of the paragraphs in one container, and id the container as 'listStuff'.

Just change the `var perPage = 2` to whatever you want (ie: 5).

Working demo: http://bootply.com/66815

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much! And bootply is a really good tool, I'm new to the whole bootstrap world. :D

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for bootstrap 3. Do you know what modifications should be made to fix it?

Comment: nevermind, it worked when I went to the link [http://bootply.com/66815](http://bootply.com/66815) and clicked on full screen preview, viewed page source, and used the inline jQuery there...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8wu6vt8r/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using jQuery v3, use `.length` instead of `.size()` on the third line.

```
var numItems = listElement.children().length;
```

Comment: Just what I needed. This small change makes it work fro jQuery 3.0 or higher. Thanks!